# ElasticSearch CouchDB Geo location

Tags: elasticsearch, shapes, geo

I am trying to get elasticsearch to index a couchdb river without luck. 
I have a database 'pl1' with only one document '1' in it. 
This is a printout of the entire document pretty-printed:

```
curl -XGET localhost:5984/pl1/1 | python -mjson.tool

{
    "_id": "1", 
    "_rev": "1-0442f3962cffedc2238fcdb28dd77557", 
    "location": {
        "geo_json": {
            "coordinates": [
                59.70141999133738, 
                14.162789164118708
            ], 
            "type": "point"
        }, 
        "lat": 14.162789164118708, 
         "lon": 59.70141999133738
    }
}
```

I create a couchdb river and index with a catch-all type called all_entries the following way:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/pl1/_meta' -d '
{
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "filter" : null,
        "db" : "pl1"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "pl1",
        "type" : "all_entries",
        "bulk_size" : "100",
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }
}'   


{"ok":true,"_index":"_river","_type":"pl1","_id":"_meta","_version":1}
```

To test whether the document was indexed I perform the following query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/pl1/all_entries/_count?pretty=true
{
    "count" : 1,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    }
}
```

But then nothing. I can't figure out how to index the location using a geo_shape type (I have also tried with the different geo_point format for the data, and indexing that, but also no results)

How do I specify a mapper and query for this?